# outer element height when chid has float

Tags: css, css-float

```
<div id="contenetarea" style="width:1000px; margin:auto">
<div id="mainarea" style="width:650px;float:left;">
</div>
<div id="sidebar" style="width:350px;float:left;">
</div>
</div>
```

I want contentarea height=max(mainarea.height,sidebar.height)
I have a problem with google cse result page..
How can i fix it?

Is there a way to do this: mainarea.height=sidebar.height=max(mainarea.height,sidebar.height)

Comment: You mean you want `overflow: hidden;` on the `contentarea` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `#contentarea`. That will cause it to wrap everything inside of it, even floated elements.

Comment: this should be the correct answer..
Wait for a moment to find and delete a js script that's fix the contentarea height..See also the edit to my original post

Comment: the problem for google results remains
Height of mainarea=sidebar.height and then the rest hidden